# Hoe to get rid off anchor link id jump on page reload?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page is jumping to anchor link id on page reload.I want to get rid of it.I am using javascript only no jquery.

This is my website
https://agility.netlify.app

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: this is not a direct coding issue. This is a server issue. With ID-links you manipulating the url activly. as such a pagereload will also jump directly to the element with the ID as you specifically call for it. If you want to stop that, you have to either stop the url from gettign changed or need a server setting (such as .htaccess) to reroute by default.

Comment: how to do that ???...I want to exclude id from URL param on page refresh